# Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense Info like Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2012, documentation, intellisense

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2012 to show documentation as in Eclipse ?

```
Visual studio
```

[image: Not as this]

```
Eclipse
```

[image: But as this]

Comment: you can go with [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) would appear and gives you hints to the source, you're about to use. If you want to get Information about your own sourcecode, you need to make marks on the Methods, Fields or Properties to tell IntelliSense that this info should be displayed.

Copy paste this small method and try to use it. You will notice IntelliSense give's you hints to use it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a number to another
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">start value</param>
/// <param name="b">new int to add</param>
/// <returns>addition of a and b</returns>
private int AddNumber(int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

If this wont fit your needs, try [ReSharper from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html). It has a bunch of functions to help you write code faster.

Comment: the hints of intellisense are not helpful. as you can see from my uploaded pictures there is hint only declarations but it is not helpful as information in eclipse. i am interested in C++ functions not that i have coded

Comment: What Dennis is telling you is that when those comments are in place, you will see something very similar to what Eclipse shows. You are relying on whoever wrote the function to help you I suppose, but your question was will VS show you, and it will **if the comments are there**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ReSharper is a good tool but it is not helpful for C++.
i think visual assist x is better.
also i have noticed that after installing resharper my visual studio started to work very slow, but with visual assist x there is no such problem.